# Struggling to get a job contract/start date after accepted written offer

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, contracts, hiring, background-check

I'm growing quite irritated so I'd appreciate any input please..

I accepted a written (conditional) job offer with Company X more than 2 weeks ago and there's no contract in sight. Since there was no contract and no info, I followed up with the recruiter with hiring manager in cc - and got a reply that blamed back-end office issues, implied another delay of up to 2 weeks and sounded rather defensive. My start date is to be delayed by at least 3 weeks.

I submitted documents for a background check a month ago (both me and the position is in EU but the company is originally based in the US). The company conducting the check is known to be problematic and the uni where I got my Masters degree apparently changed the name 3 years ago (= the uni name on the diploma doesn't exist anymore, which I only found out today).

For context, I worked for this company previously as a contractor, have glowing internal references and love the team I'd work with. However, the recruitment is leaving a bad taste in my mouth - the entire process is sloppy, delayed and the recruiter has shown questionable practices such as always replying within 1-2 weeks but pressuring me to decide on the offer within a day due to their PTO, or visible confusion about both the package and the position. I'm also baffled by the tone of the last e-mail.

Is there something fishy going on? Is it just a stuck background check?
I'm currently employed but not happy in the job - I was much happier in the Company X...

Comment: "I accepted a written (conditional) job offer with Company X more than 2 weeks ago " have the conditions been removed or is there something else besides the background checks?

Comment: background checks are the only condition - and there I've heard nothing since submitting past employment contracts and the diploma (a month ago); I e-mailed Sterling today what the status is (plus informing them about the uni name change)

Comment: Unless you work in HR/recruiting, I wouldn't judge the rest of the work environment by how they work.

Answer (score 2):

As someone with a third-person position, we really cannot tell what is the actual cause of the delay, however, seeing that you mentioned

> *"For context, I worked for this company previously as a contractor, have glowing internal references and love the team I'd work with."*

and

> *"I'm currently employed"*

I'd say, wait out the delay. The hiring needs to happen once, your workplace is a much more impactful entity in your daily life (and career). If you love what you (will) do and with whom you work, these initial hiccups will not be a problem soon after.

Also, if you see this going beyond the revised timeline, I'd suggest not to *rely* on this anymore, and look for other opportunities, too, if you really want to shift jobs.

Comment: I'm buying a '_k_' - too little for an edit.. Otherwise sound advise!

Comment: Reminders: standard advice is that you should not stop job hunting (or quit your previous job) until you have a signed contract with committed start date. Offers can and do fall through, for many reasons, not just because something odd happened during background check.